# What is the right way to invalidate tags in RTKQ after a Firestore write operation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tags, rtk-query

**THE ENVIRONMENT**
A ReactJS application that performs writes and read against a Firestore DB with the `Firebase client SDK v9.17.1`.
The business logic is inside RTK Query's `queryFn`s, so for example I call an `updateTodo` endpoint with the `useUpdateTodoMutation` hook and it does something like this:

```js
updateTodo: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async ({ userId, todoId, data }) => {
        const docRef = doc(getFirestore(), `users/${userId}/todos/${todoId}`);
        await updateDoc(docRef, data);
        return { data: undefined };
      },
      invalidatesTags: [API_TAGS.TODOS],
}),
```

And I perform my fetchAll in this way

```js
fetchTodos: builder.query({
      queryFn: async ({ userId, options }) => {
        const getAllTodosQuery = query(
          collection(getFirestore(), `users/${userId}/todos`),
          ...(options?.whereClauses || []),
          ...(options?.orderBy ? [options.orderBy] : []),
          ...(options?.limit ? [options.limit] : []),
        );

        const { docs } = await getDocs(getAllTodosQuery);

        const items = docs.map((d) => d.data());

        return { data: { items } };
      },
      providesTags: [API_TAGS.TODOS],
}),
```

**THE PROBLEM**
The `invalidatesTags` call is performed not when the data are effectively written on the Firestore disk, but it seems like the Firestore SDK is giving the `OK` response in advance, so the automatical refetching performed by RTK has no effect.

**THE WORKAROUND**
Of course reloading the page works but it's not a solution. At the moment I'm doing a manual refetch, updating my cache manually:

```js
updateTodo: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async ({ userId, todoId, data }, { dispatch }) => {
        const docRef = doc(getFirestore(), `users/${userId}/todos/${todoId}`);
        await updateDoc(docRef, data);

        const todoDoc = await getDoc(docRef);

        dispatch(todosApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('fetchTodos', { userId }, () => todoDoc.data()));
        return { data: undefined };
      },
      invalidatesTags: [API_TAGS.TODOS],
}),
```

This way it's working nicely but I miss all the auto-refetching of RTK that is very good.

--

Is there any solution? Am I missing something?